# Getting Windows Live Anonymous ID from PC?

Tags: windows-phone-7, zune

Is there any way of getting the "Windows Live Anonymous ID" from a PC based on the users e-mail-adress, logged in Windows-account, registry, Zune, currently usb-connected phone or else?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Windows Live Anonymous ID", but if you mean the Windows Live ID that is associated with the device, then no there is no way to retrieve this from the device, or the other places you suggest. If you require a Windows Live ID from a user, you should ask them for it because a) it's polite, and b) they might want to use a different account for your application.

Comment: The "Windows Live Anonymous ID" or ANID is a hash of the Live ID associated with the phone. This can be used to track users across multiple devices. Get it on the device via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.getvalue(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Cool thanks for the info. We learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to query information on a phone from a connected PC.

Any such ability could be considered a security hole.